# How to get `npm root` for given directory (different from current one)?

Tags: bash, npm, zsh, yeoman

I would like to get the `npm root` for a given directory (without being in that directory). The [docs doesn't list any argument](https://npmjs.org/doc/root.html) and the following don't give any results:

```
npm root /path/to/project # contains a node_modules directory
```

This is in order to create a `zsh` plugin to auto-complete `yeoman`/`yo` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute it in a sub-shell which won't change your current directory:

```
(cd /path/to/project && exec npm root)
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but was looking for a more elegant solution (hoping for an option/argument form)

Comment: Then I don't get why you would ask. I'm sure you already looked at the source: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/lib/root.js

Comment: only at https://npmjs.org/doc/root.html and not all option are present in this doc (e.g. --silent, --parseable).